# Have a directory appear everywhere in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, alias

I'm making a project using [iWebKit](http://snippetspace.com/projects/iwebkit/). I When I include the files, I don't want to have to keep linking back to the directory the framework is in like:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css">
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css">
<link href="../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css">
<link href="../../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css">
```

I want to be able to have the same directory in every other directory so localhost/css/style.css is the same as localhost/some/other/directory/css/style.css.

I am using Apache and want to know if there is a way to do this with .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this my using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

For this add the following to the .htaccess file in the root of your application

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^.*/css/([^./]*)\.css$ /css/$1.css [L]
```

Here the Regular Expression `^.*/css/([^./]*)\.css$` matches any string with /css/any_name.css in the end, and rewrites the URL to point internally to css folder in the root. And [L] means it is the last rule to match if it matches. And $1 refers to the parenthesized portion of the Regular Expression that matches the URL, which is the name of the stylesheet

For more complex scenarios I would suggest you read up some more on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

Use absolute paths

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css">
```

Note the `/` in from of the path.